# Error Initalizing Stable diffusion with python 3.10.6. 'str' object has no attribute 'isascii'

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.10, stable-diffusion

I'm trying to set Up Stable Diffusion 1.5 from GIT https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui.
I've followed a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycQJDJ-qNI8&t=0s.

To avoid problems with multiple python versions I've removed older Python version and installed only Python 3.10.6, then only 3.10.9, but I receive the same error with both versions.

When I call the web-user.bat to Initialize. The bat calls webui.bat and I receive this error:

```
Python 3.10.9
venv "D:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 85, in search_function
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 64, in normalize_encoding
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isascii'
Premere un tasto per continuare . . .
```

I've seen this error is due to using an old python version, but I'm using the 3.10.

Thanks

Comment: Was `venv` created before you uninstalled the older versions of Python? Maybe it needs to be deleted and recreated?

Comment: `str.isascii` was added in Python3.7, so it seems likely that there is something wrong with your Python installation.

Comment: @DanGetz it surely was created before, I'll go check it out

Comment: @snakecharmerb this is probable and that's why I completely removed and install python two or three times. Is there something I can do to check if it is really a clean installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was I had a old version of Python when using `web-user.bat` for the first time. When You run the `web-user.bat` the first time it creates a venv folder.

The solution was to remove manually the `venv` folder from my Stable Diffusion folder and use again the `web-user.bat`.